# How can I load an URL from a form-button instead of making and clicking a text-link?

Tags: javascript, php

I have

```js
jQuery( "#art-calendar-"+infoModalType+"-event-link-url" ).html('<a target="_blank" href="'+calendarEvent.eventLinkUrl+'">'+calendarEvent.eventLinkUrl+'</a>');
```

in my .js file

and

```js
<button type="button" id="button-1"  type="submit">  
                    Button that loads new page
                    </button>
```

in .php file

How can I make a button with custom text, that, onclick, loads a new page instead of showing the url?

Comment: So you want the button to have a [tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)? You can add a click handler to the button directly if you are using javascript anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This line had to go into the javascript file:

```js
jQuery('#Termin').attr('action', calendarEvent.eventLinkUrl);
```

and the next three lines into the PHP file:

```html
<form id="Termin" action="" method="post">
      <button type="submit">jetzt Termin buchen</button>
</form>
```

The jQuery command **adds** the calendarEvent + EventURL into the empty action-attribute of the form button called #Termin. This way, the form gets a dynamically produced URL that is being loaded, when clicking the button with the ID Termin.